# Is it possible to use the -A paramter on a grep command to print every other line?

Tags: grep

As I'm reading from a file, I want to grep every instance of 'x' from that file (line 1), along with the next line (line 2), and the line after that (line 3)... but then I want lines 6, 7, 10 and 11. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: At the moment I'm just using `grep -A10` and using if-statements to skip over the undesired lines, but the program takes almost 30 minutes to run and I'm trying to optimise it a little by getting rid of the if-statements.

Comment: What do you want to happen for overlapping matches?  For example, if `x` appears on line 1 and also on line 3, what lines do you want printed?

Comment: All the lines will be unique because of the dataset I'm working with. Each line has a unique <tag> at the start, but the tags are repeated every 15 lines or so.

Comment: ^^ Does that reference to a `<tag>` mean it's XML? If so, why not use an XML parser to parse the XML? Either way, I think it would help if you could give us an example of the file, please, so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: The files are .dat files containing reviews for hotels. The structure of every file is roughly as follows:

`<Author> (username of the person who wrote the review)   
<Content> (The review)   
<Date> (When they wrote the review)`   

And so on, with other tags

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the input file is regular text.  Alternatively, if the input file is actually XML or JSON or similar, then tools specific to that format should be used.

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[0];a[1];a[2];a[3];a[6];a[7];a[10];a[11]} /x/{n=NR} n && (NR-n) in a'
```

How it works:

- `BEGIN{a[0];a[1];a[2];a[3];a[6];a[7];a[10];a[11]}`

  This initializes associative array `a` for each of the lines that we want to print.
- `/x/{n=NR}`

  If `x` appears on this line, set variable `n` to the current line number.  Note that `x` is treated as a regular expression.
- `n && (NR-n) in a`

  If `n` has been assigned and `NR-n` is one of the lines that we want to print, then print the line.